# How to "carve out" matched values using POSIX awk which does not support back-reference

Tags: awk, regular-expression

Given inputs like:

```
input value #001 is [342]
input value #002 is [8349]
```

How to carve out the values inside [...] so the output is below?

```
342
8349
```

This should be easy with regular expressions that supports back reference (e.g., "\1"). But POSIX awk, which uses ERE, doesn't support that.

For example, POSIX sed supports back-reference, so:

```bash
<input sed -E 's/^.*\[([[:digit:]]+)\].*$/\1/'
```

How to do this in POSIX awk?

Comment: Is the bracketed field always the last field on the line? Is every last field bracketed? Is it always just 1 field per line that's bracketed? If the input can look in any way different from what you've shown so far where the last field on every line is inside brackets then please [edit] your question to provide more truly representative sample input/output.

Comment: `-E` is not part of POSIX sed btw. In a POSIX sed your command would have to be written as `sed 's/^.*\[\([[:digit:]]\{1,\}\)\].*$/\1/'` or `sed 's/^.*\[\([[:digit:]]*\)\].*$/\1/'`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `match()` which sets `RSTART` to the start of the match and `RLENGTH` to its length (it also returns `RSTART`; or 0 if there's no match):

```
awk 'match($0, /\[[[:digit:]]+\]/) {
       print substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)
     }'
```

Or:

```
awk 'match($0, /\[[[:digit:]]+\]/) {
       print substr($0, RSTART+1, RLENGTH-2)
     }'
```

If you only want the number without the brackets.

Note that mawk doesn't support POSIX character classes, and `[[:digit:]]` matches on more decimal digits than 0123456789 in some locales on some systems. Use `[0123456789]` if you only want to match on those (not `[0-9]`).

Note that if there's more than one occurrence of `[digits]` in a line, that `awk` code will return the first while your `sed` variant would return the last (because of the greedy `.*` at the start).

Answer (score 1):

The following command uses `gsub` to delete all `[` and `]` characters from the last field of input of each line, and then prints that field:

```bash
$ awk '{ gsub("[][]", "", $NF); print $NF }' file
342
8349
```

Similarly with `sed`, by removing everything up to the last space character on each line, and then the `[` and `]` from whatever is left:

```bash
$ sed -e 's/.* //' -e 's/[][]//g' file
342
8349
```

Or, using `tr` to remove the `[` and `]` characters after `awk` or `sed` have isolated the last field:

```bash
$ awk '{ print $NF }' file | tr -d '[]'
342
8349
$ sed 's/.* //' file | tr -d '[]'
342
8349
```

Note too that `sed -E` is not supported by POSIX (yet).